# Open Source Server Monitor API

Tags: monitoring

I'm looking for an open source linux tool that allows me to POST (curl) server statistics to a web application for processing.

I've done a bit of research and haven't found anything. Anyone know of something similar?

Last ditch effort before I code it myself.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Diamond ( https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Diamond ) has a HTTP Post handler. Any metrics it collects can be posted do any url.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [collectd + collection](http://collectd.org/) and/or [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/getting-your-data-into-graphite) for data collection *and* display.

Both can export PNG images you may display somewhere else.

I'm not sure if you're locked in to using this web app of yours to display data, I'd reconsider using something ready-made.

Handling data efficiently is no easy task, I'd rather use some solution where people put a lot of thought into that.